# Java, implicit and explicit type casting of lists of generic enabled objects

Tags: java, generics

I've always wondered about a thing when working with Java and databases. I use a database abstraction layer and get my results like this:

```
Hashtable h = connection.selectRow("select * from table where id = 5");
```

However, when returning a number of rows in the same format, it returns this:

```
ArrayList<Hashtable> a = connection.selectAll("select * from table where id > 5");
```

Now, as I like generics, I wanted to take full advantage of it by using

```
ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>> a = connection.selectAll("select * from table where id > 5");
```

But this will not compile:

```
Cannot convert from ArrayList<Hashtable> to ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>>.
```

However, split up like this, it works:

```
ArrayList<Hashtable> a = connection.selectAll("select * from table where id > 5");
Hashtable<String,String> h = a.get(0);
```

This only produces a type safety warning:

```
Type safety: The expression of type Hashtable needs unchecked conversion to conform to Hashtable<String,String>.
```

It seems as if the one step above would do the same as these two lines here, but mashed together into one Java refuses to do the conversion. I suspect some internal mechanism responsible for this behaviour, but have yet to find the reason.

Would anyone care to elaborate?

Edit: Just to clarify. When in my example the error message says

```
Cannot convert from ArrayList<Hashtable> to ArrayList<Hashtable<String,String>>.
```

when in the lines below, Java seems very capable of the same thing it just told me it cannot do when I use

```
Hashtable<String,String> h = a.get(0);
```

it seems to me that Java is lying to me. Not deliberately, of course, we like each other. But there must be a reason. And that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: could you please tell me of which class your `connection` object is?

Comment: It's a class from our data abstraction layer which implements the selectAll(), selectRow() and selectColumn() methods with sensitive return types (ArrayList<Hashtable>, Hashtable and ArrayList, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `connection.selectAll()` is `ArrayList<Hashtable>`. That's what has to be on the left side.

Because of that, when you say

```
ArrayList<Hashtable> a = connection.selectAll("select * from table where id > 5");
Hashtable<String,String> h = a.get(0);
```

You get a warning. `a.get(0)` is returning a `Hashtable` (non-generic) and you're assigning it to `Hashtable<String,String>`.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems / flaws here.

1. Hashtable is synchronized. Unless there is a real need to have a synchronized map, Hashtables aren't recommended. You could instead use `Collections.synchronizedMap` for this.
2. Your entity model is wrong. A Map datastructure shouldn't be used for operations such as these. Instead, you should create an entity for each table. If the table is about employees, create a class called Employee with different attributes mapping to the columns in the database.
3. The `connection.select*` methods don't seem to be genericised, meaning you can't just use generics on the left hand side of the method call.
4. To summarise, the class from which instances of `connection` objects are created is so not right.

Comment: Tahnk you. I am well aware of the problems of this approach to data abstraction. It is not mine, I merely am in the position to fix it when it breaks until we can replace it with a real solution.

Comment: Ah ok :) In that case, you don't really have much flexibility, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution i think you could actually type your class like

```
public class yourConnectionClass<E>
```

in that class you could change the Returntyoe of your method:

```
public <E> HashMap<E,E> selectAll()
```

if you now create an object of your class like this:

```
connection = new yourConnectionClass<String>();
```

i think this should work so that the returntype of the method should now be `Hashmap<String,String>`

I really hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8

> assignment from `Vector` to `Vector<String>` is unsafe (since the raw vector might have had a different element type), but is still permitted using unchecked conversion (§5.1.9) in order to enable interfacing with legacy code

raw type support is half-assed; some of simple cases like this are allowed to ease transition.